# ACF: Display category name using taxonomy field

Tags: categories, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently using the taxonomy field in ACF, with the aim of printing the category name in the front end. Using it like so:

```
<?php $term = get_sub_field('category_selector'); if( $term ): ?>
<span><?php echo $term->name; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which is currently displaying nothing, I've debugged the `$term` which doesn't display the category ID of `3`, but for some reason I can't get hold of the category name from this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `var_dump($term);`?

Comment: @s_ha_dum that gives: `ARRAY(1) { [0]=> INT(3) }`

Comment: When you add the taxonomy field to your field group, one of the options is to return the Term ID or Term object. You currently have ID selected. Every ACF field that associates some sort of object has this option.

Comment: @Milo even with term object selected, the above code still isn't returning anything?

Comment: @Milo ah actually, nearly there, I var dumped it with 'term object' selected and got this like so: `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2150 (11) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Product Category"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(16) "product-category"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(21) "wpsc_product_category"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    int(2)
    ["object_id"]=>
    int(59)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
}`

Comment: @Milo I can't understand why `<?php echo $term->name; ?>` isn't working though?

Comment: you have the field set to allow multiple values, so you get an *array* of objects back. you have to loop over with a foreach, as in @s_ha_dum answer

Comment: @Milo the field is only set to allow a single value, even trying the below answer returns nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `3` is a category ID...

```
$term = get_sub_field('category_selector'); 
if( $term ) {
  foreach($term as $t) {
    $t = get_category($t);
    echo $t->name;
  }
}
```

In other words, it looks like ACF is just storing the ID, not the whole object, so you need to use that ID to grab the category object before you have access to the name, slug, etc.